# HEROKU asyncio_redis.exceptions.ErrorReply: NOAUTH Authentication required

Tags: python, heroku, celery, fastapi

I'm trying to host a framework on Heroku, where I have a dyno for an api in fastapi or dyno for celery beat and another dyno for celery worker. In addition to having the following addons
Redis Enterprise Cloud,
Stackhero for RabbitMQ,
Heroku Postgres. So far everything seems to be working fine, both use redis, both the fastapi and celery api. The problem is that when I issue some task to the worker, it gives me this error. `asyncio_redis.exceptions.ErrorReply: NOAUTH Authentication required`

Here is my configuration file

```py
import os
import pathlib
from functools import lru_cache

from kombu import Queue


def route_task(name, args, kwargs, options, task=None, **kw):
    if ":" in name:
        queue, _ = name.split(":")
        return {"queue": queue}
    return {"queue": "default"}


class BaseConfig:
    BASE_DIR: pathlib.Path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent
    UPLOADS_DEFAULT_DEST: str = str(BASE_DIR / "upload")

    DATABASE_URL: str = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", f"sqlite:///{BASE_DIR}/db.sqlite3")
    DATABASE_CONNECT_DICT: dict = {}

    CELERY_BROKER_URL: str = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0")
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: str = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0")

    WS_MESSAGE_QUEUE: str = os.environ.get("WS_MESSAGE_QUEUE", "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0")

    CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE: dict = {
        # "task-schedule-work": {
        #     "task": "task_schedule_work",
        #     "schedule": 5.0,  # five seconds
        # },
    }

    CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE: str = "default"

    # Force all queues to be explicitly listed in `CELERY_TASK_QUEUES` to help prevent typos
    CELERY_TASK_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES: bool = False

    CELERY_TASK_QUEUES: list = (
        # need to define default queue here or exception would be raised
        Queue("default"),

        Queue("high_priority"),
        Queue("low_priority"),
    )

    CELERY_TASK_ROUTES = (route_task,)


class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    pass


class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
    CELERY_BROKER_URL: str = os.environ.get("STACKHERO_RABBITMQ_AMQP_URL_TLS")
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: str = os.environ.get("REDISCLOUD_URL")
    WS_MESSAGE_QUEUE: str = os.environ.get("REDISCLOUD_URL")
    


class TestingConfig(BaseConfig):
    # https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-database/
    DATABASE_URL: str = "sqlite:///./test.db"
    DATABASE_CONNECT_DICT: dict = {"check_same_thread": False}


@lru_cache()
def get_settings():
    config_cls_dict = {
        "development": DevelopmentConfig,
        "production": ProductionConfig,
        "testing": TestingConfig
    }

    config_name = os.environ.get("FASTAPI_CONFIG", "development")
    config_cls = config_cls_dict[config_name]
    return config_cls()


settings = get_settings()
```

celery utils:

```
import functools

from celery import current_app as current_celery_app, shared_task
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from celery.utils.time import get_exponential_backoff_interval

from project.config import settings


def create_celery():
    celery_app = current_celery_app
    celery_app.config_from_object(settings, namespace="CELERY")

    return celery_app


def get_task_info(task_id):
    """
    return task info according to the task_id
    """
    task = AsyncResult(task_id)
    state = task.state

    if state == "FAILURE":
        error = str(task.result)
        response = {
            "state": task.state,
            "error": error,
        }
    else:
        response = {
            "state": task.state,
        }
    return response


class custom_celery_task:

    EXCEPTION_BLOCK_LIST = (
        IndexError,
        KeyError,
        TypeError,
        UnicodeDecodeError,
        ValueError,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.task_args = args
        self.task_kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except self.EXCEPTION_BLOCK_LIST:
                # do not retry for those exceptions
                raise
            except Exception as e:
                # here we add Exponential Backoff just like Celery
                countdown = self._get_retry_countdown(task_func)
                raise task_func.retry(exc=e, countdown=countdown)

        task_func = shared_task(*self.task_args, **self.task_kwargs)(wrapper_func)
        return task_func

    def _get_retry_countdown(self, task_func):
        retry_backoff = int(
            self.task_kwargs.get("retry_backoff", True)
        )
        retry_backoff_max = int(
            self.task_kwargs.get("retry_backoff_max", 600)
        )
        retry_jitter = self.task_kwargs.get(
            "retry_jitter", True
        )

        countdown = get_exponential_backoff_interval(
            factor=retry_backoff,
            retries=task_func.request.retries,
            maximum=retry_backoff_max,
            full_jitter=retry_jitter
        )

        return countdown
```

**init**.py where together all:

```
from broadcaster import Broadcast
from fastapi import FastAPI

from project.config import settings

broadcast = Broadcast(settings.WS_MESSAGE_QUEUE)


def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI()

    from project.logging import configure_logging
    configure_logging()

    # do this before loading routes
    from project.celery_utils import create_celery
    app.celery_app = create_celery()

    from project.users import users_router
    app.include_router(users_router)

    from project.tdd import tdd_router
    app.include_router(tdd_router)

    from project.ws import ws_router
    app.include_router(ws_router)

    from project.ws.views import register_socketio_app
    register_socketio_app(app)

    @app.on_event("startup")
    async def startup_event():
        await broadcast.connect()

    @app.on_event("shutdown")
    async def shutdown_event():
        await broadcast.disconnect()

    @app.get("/")
    async def root():
        return {"message": "Hello World"}

    return app
```

I would expect them both to use the same instance if they have problems.

Comment: Noone is going to be able to help you without you showing your code.

Comment: updated post. Thank for the you comment

Comment: It looks like an authentication issue, you probably need to provide your redis URL as `redis://username:password@host:port` in `CELERY_BROKER_URL` and `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`.

Comment: I'm using rabbitmq in CELERY_BROKER_URL, my problem is only in production and development everything is fine. Before migrating to Heroku I was using rabbitqm in docker-compose and it was working normally.

Comment: But are you using the correct username/password in production?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes friend, I'm using the host and password that Heroku created when I started both the rabbitqm and redis addons

Comment: After hours of investigation I discovered the problem, follow the [issue](https://github.com/encode/broadcaster/issues/103)